# Using GZIP Module with Python

Tags: python, gzip

I'm trying to use the Python GZIP module to simply uncompress several .gz files in a directory. Note that I do not want to read the files, only uncompress them. After searching this site for a while, I have this code segment, but it does not work:

```
import gzip
import glob
import os
for file in glob.glob(PATH_TO_FILE + "/*.gz"):
    #print file
    if os.path.isdir(file) == False:
        shutil.copy(file, FILE_DIR)
        # uncompress the file
        inF = gzip.open(file, 'rb')
        s = inF.read()
        inF.close()
```

the .gz files are in the correct location, and I can print the full path + filename with the print command, but the GZIP module isn't getting executed properly. what am I missing?

Comment: Is the file ok? You don't show what is/isn't happening.

Comment: Yes, the file is ok. I can uncompress the file using gunzip onthe UNIX command line.

Answer (score 40):

If you get no error, the gzip module probably is being executed properly, and **the file is already getting decompressed**.

The precise definition of "decompressed" varies on context:

> I do not want to read the files, only uncompress them

The `gzip` module doesn't work as a desktop archiving program like 7-zip - you can't "uncompress" a file without "reading" it. Note that "reading" (in programming) usually just means "storing (temporarily) in the computer RAM", not "opening the file in the GUI".

**What you *probably* mean by "uncompress" (as in a desktop archiving program) is more precisely described (in programming) as "read a in-memory stream/buffer from a compressed file, and write it to a new file (and possibly delete the compressed file afterwards)"**

```
inF = gzip.open(file, 'rb')
s = inF.read()
inF.close()
```

With these lines, you're just reading the stream. If you expect a new "uncompressed" file to be created, **you just need to write the buffer to a new file**:

```
with open(out_filename, 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(s)
```

If you're dealing with very large files (larger than the amount of your RAM), you'll need to adopt a different approach. But that is the topic for another question.

Comment: No error occurs when I run the Python script, but the gzip file isn't uncompressed. I only want to uncompress the file so it can be used by another tool, not re-written to a file, or used elsewhere in my script.

Comment: @user3111358 What do mean, *exactly* by "the gzip file isn't uncompressed"? What makes you say so? Have you checked the contents of `s` in your code?

Comment: What I mean is the gzip file isn't uncompressed, which is what I am trying to do. I ONLY want to uncompress, nothing else.

Comment: @user3111358 What I'm trying to say is that "uncompress" means different things in different contexts. My bet is that if you ask a few people who've read your code here on SO, they'll tell you the file **is** being uncompressed. Thus, I must ask: how do you **know** the file is not being "uncompressed"? Is it because there are no new files being put on the same directory as the compressed file when you run the code?

Comment: This is the correct answer. When you decompress a file it is written to a new file and the previous compressed file is either deleted as another action, or the the compressed file is maintained. Either way, a new uncompressed file is written.

Answer (score 6):

You're decompressing file into `s` variable, and do nothing with it. You should stop searching stackoverflow and read at least python tutorial. Seriously.

Anyway, there's several thing wrong with your code:

1. you need is to STORE the unzipped data in `s` into some file.
2. there's no need to copy the actual `*.gz` files. Because in your code, you're unpacking the original gzip file and not the copy.
3. you're using `file`, which is a reserved word, as a variable. This is not
   an error, just a very bad practice.

This should probably do what you wanted:

```
import gzip
import glob
import os
import os.path

for gzip_path in glob.glob(PATH_TO_FILE + "/*.gz"):
    if os.path.isdir(gzip_path) == False:
        inF = gzip.open(gzip_path, 'rb')
        # uncompress the gzip_path INTO THE 's' variable
        s = inF.read()
        inF.close()

        # get gzip filename (without directories)
        gzip_fname = os.path.basename(gzip_path)
        # get original filename (remove 3 characters from the end: ".gz")
        fname = gzip_fname[:-3]
        uncompressed_path = os.path.join(FILE_DIR, fname)

        # store uncompressed file data from 's' variable
        open(uncompressed_path, 'w').write(s)
```

Comment: When you call `open(uncompressed_path, 'w').write(s)` without assigning the file handler to a variable there is no need to close the file handler?

Comment: @Ander - yes, because the (anonymous) file object will never be assigned to a variable and therefore it will be destroyed immediately after executing. I find it much cleaner for simple "write xy to file" or "read from file" - that is when there is _exactly_ one read or write. But if you do more than one read/write, you should probably always use `with open(...):`

Answer (score 6):

You should use `with` to open files and, of course, store the result of reading the compressed file. See [`gzip` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open):

```
import gzip
import glob
import os
import os.path

for gzip_path in glob.glob("%s/*.gz" % PATH_TO_FILE):
    if not os.path.isdir(gzip_path):
        with gzip.open(gzip_path, 'rb') as in_file:
            s = in_file.read()

        # Now store the uncompressed data
        path_to_store = gzip_fname[:-3]  # remove the '.gz' from the filename

        # store uncompressed file data from 's' variable
        with open(path_to_store, 'w') as f:
            f.write(s)
```

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you might want to have a look at [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) and its `'r:gz'` option for opening files.

Comment: It would be nicer to use `os.path.splitext(gzip_fname)[0]` to remove the `.gz` extension

Comment: your example is wrong, `gzip_fname` doesn't exist, you have to change it to `gzip_path`. Furthermore, what you get into `gzip_path` is not a path, it's the gz file. Therefore you should change `os.path.isdir` to `os.path.isfile` I also think that to use @gotson solution is nicer :)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the subprocess module:

```
for file in glob.glob(PATH_TO_FILE + "/*.gz"):
    if os.path.isdir(file) == False:
        shutil.copy(file, FILE_DIR)
        # uncompress the file
        subprocess.call(["gunzip", FILE_DIR + "/" + os.path.basename(file)])
```

Since my goal was to simply uncompress the archive, the above code accomplishes this. The archived files are located in a central location, and are copied to a working area, uncompressed, and used in a test case. the GZIP module was too complicated for what I was trying to accomplish.

Thanks for everyone's help. It is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to programmatically manipulate the contents of the code and don't mind if it isn't interoperable between OSes, then this is a much more intuitive way to approach things.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a much simpler solution than the others presented given the op only wanted to extract all the files in a directory:

```
import glob
from setuptools import archive_util

for fn in glob.glob('*.gz'):
  archive_util.unpack_archive(fn, '.')
```

Comment: Archive_util.unpack_archive does not seem to support .gz. The error message is "setuptools.archive_util.UnrecognizedFormat: Not a recognized archive type: K:\z_temp\file.gz". Also shutil.upack_archive does not support .gz. To see the supported types of files for shutil_unpack_archive: `import shutil; print(shutil.get_archive_formats())`